# How do I create accounts in AD Users container using DSC?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, dsc

I've got a section in my DSC-configuration that creates new accounts in a specified OU.
(Input parameters are omitted in the example below.)
Please ignore that I'm currently handling passwords with `-AsPlainText`

```
Import-DscResource -ModuleName ActiveDirectoryDsc -ModuleVersion 6.0.1

$Count = 0
foreach ($Principal in $Node.Principals) {
  $Count++
  ADUser "Create_$($Principal.Name)_$Count" {
    UserName     = $Principal.Name
    DomainName   = $Node.DomainName
    Path         = (@($Principal.Path, $DistinguishedNameSuffix) |
                      where { ![string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($_) }
                   ) -join ','
    Password     = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential(
                     "$($Node.DomainName)\$($Principal.Name)", 
                     (ConvertTo-SecureString $Principal.Password -AsPlainText -Force)
                   )                   
    PasswordNeverExpires = $true
    Ensure       = 'Present'
    DependsOn    = @('[WaitForADDomain]DscDomainWait')
  }
}
```

But when trying to create users in the AD container Users (which is not an OU), the configuration will fail.

Is there a way to create accounts in that container using DSC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the answer was pretty simple.
I just used search to find the `Distinguished Name` of the `Users` container...

[image]

So, using `CN=` instead of `OU=` in the `Path` input parameter of the DSC-config did the trick :)

So the issue was with the very thing I omitted to include in my question.